# Python runtime error in tactical game: dict object not callable

Tags: python, dictionary, runtime

I am currently having an issue with a rather extensive Python program I have written. The program is a tactical calculator for a game and is shown below.

```
# Tactical Calculator

budget = int(input("budget per round:"))
amount = int(input("ingots per round:"))
rounds = int(input("rounds:"))
infantry_budget = {'assault': 80,
            'light': 90,
            'motorized': 100,
            'commando': 150}
engine_budget = {'armored': 135,
          'tank': 180,
          'heavy tank': 240,
          'super tank': None}
artillery_budget = {'battalion': 120,
             'field': 200,
             'rocket': 220}
amount1 = [int((budget * rounds) / infantry_budget["light"]), int((budget * rounds) / infantry_budget["assault"]), int((budget * rounds) / infantry_budget["motorized"]),
                     int((budget * rounds) / infantry_budget["commando"])]
print(amount1)
amount2 = [int((budget * rounds) / engine_budget['armored']), int((budget * rounds) / engine_budget(['tank'])), int((budget * rounds) / engine_budget['heavy tank'])]
print(amount2)
infantry_ingots = {'assault': 10,
                   'motorized': 30,
                   'commando': 45}
engine_ingots = {'armored': 60,
                 'tank': 90,
                 'heavy tank': 145,
                 'super tank': None}
artillery_ingots = {'battalion': 50,
                    'field': 80,
                    'rocket': 100}
```

The issue I have is that after amount1 is printed, the Python shell prints a runtime error, stating that " 'dict' object is not callable". I would please like to know why it is printing this error and how to fix it. Thank you very much for any assistance you can offer concerning this program.

Comment: You should post your full exception as it provides us additional information - however a quick glance shows - `engine_budget(['tank'])` is a function call in your `amount2 =`  line. Just remove the parens `()`

Comment: AChampion Thank you very much for your help; that fixed the program.